# Is it possible to only show questions that can be answered by beginner

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am still in the process of learning C, SQL and Java. This means that I can´t answer difficult questions but I would be happy to answer "easy questions" that can (likely) be understood as a beginner.

Is it possible to filter for these questions?
Thank you!

Comment: How would you measure the difficulty of a question?

Comment: E.g. by interpreting the code provided in the question. There should be some way to rate the difficulty of the question, e.g. by looking into a common (online) textbook and seeing when the methods used are introduced in a book. A later introduction in the book would allow to infer that it is a rather difficult question.

Comment: @SQLLearner ok, lemme rephrase the question. How do you get such a measure without having a manual review queue that assesses those? Because your idea seems to be very difficult to scale :/

Answer (score 7):

What you ask is not possible, but you could try to focus on the title of the questions.

For example, when looking at [[java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions, it's more likely you can answer a question titled *"delete image from the folder java"* compared to a question titled *"How to connect a SSL MQTT client with a CA signed server certificate?"*.

Comment: Then in C, the questions that are of the former kind are almost always off-topic - typo, no mcve, too broad etc.